# How do I get the 'checkpoint' of a retrained inception-v3 model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying use a retrained inception-v3 model in tensorflow-serving. But it seems that I have to provide a 'checkpoint'. I was wondering how do I get those 'checkpoints'? The `retrain.py` returns me a `retrained_graph.pb`. I followed this tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0)

Thank you!

Comment: check points for all google pre-trained models are available over https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? The tensorflow docs are not clear about this.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? @cookiedookie

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the API changes for Tensorflow 1.0

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration

to make it work to create a checkpoint file/s instead of .pb file.
Also refer to:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to download the checkpoints for the latest edition of pre-trained Inception V3 model:

```
$ CHECKPOINT_DIR=/tmp/checkpoints
$ mkdir ${CHECKPOINT_DIR}
$ wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz
$ mv inception_v3.ckpt ${CHECKPOINT_DIR}
$ rm inception_v3_2016_08_28.tar.gz
```